# Add() method not saving many to many field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, many-to-many

I am creating a website that allows users to follow stocks and see articles based on what they follow. After registering, the user selects the stocks they want to follow.

```
def follow_stocks_post_registration(request):
        all_stocks = Stock.objects.all()

        if request.method == 'POST':
            stocks_user_selected = request.POST.getlist('stocks_selected')
            user_profile = request.user.profile
            for stock_name in stocks_user_selected:
                stock = Stock.objects.get(name=stock_name)
                user_profile.followed_stocks.add(stock)
```

models.py:

```
class Stock(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    followed_stocks = models.ManyToManyField(Stock, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
        instance.profile.save()
```

In the view, `stocks_user_selected = request.POST.getlist('stocks_selected')` gets the correct list of stocks, but `user_profile.followed_stocks.add(stock)` does not successfully add any stock to the user's `followed_stocks`. I am not sure what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `.save()` method after adding the object to `ManyToManyField`. Also, you should filter the `stocks` in one query instead of getting them one by one.

```
def follow_stocks_post_registration(request):
    all_stocks = Stock.objects.all()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        stocks_user_selected = request.POST.getlist('stocks_selected')
        user_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        for stock in Stock.objects.filter(name__in=stocks_user_selected):
            user_profile.followed_stocks.add(stock)
            user_profile.save()
```

Comment: This still does not work, could it be that I have LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/' in my settings.py? As this view makes the user log in